# Unable to set custom Django user model to is_active

Tags: django

I recently created a custom user model in a Django 1.11 project. It's tied into [Django Registration](https://django-registration.readthedocs.io/en/3.1/) and overall is working well. However, I get an error when trying to set a user as 'active' in the admin panel. The error I get is:

```
normalize() argument 2 must be str, not None
```

With the error generated due to this function:

```
class UsernameField(forms.CharField):
    def to_python(self, value):
        return unicodedata.normalize('NFKC', super(UsernameField, self).to_python(value))
```

Here is my customer user model:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser, BaseUserManager


class UserManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, email, password):
        user = self.model(email=self.normalize_email(email))
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, email, password):
        user = self.create_user(email, password)
        user.is_staff = True
        user.is_superuser = True
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user


class User(AbstractUser):
    email = models.EmailField('email address', unique=True)
    first_name = models.CharField('first name', max_length=30, blank=True, null=True)
    last_name = models.CharField('last name', max_length=150, blank=True, null=True)
    username = models.CharField('username', max_length=150, blank=True, null=True)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []
    objects = UserManager()

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'user'
        verbose_name_plural = 'users'
```

Here is the form I use when saving new users:

```
from django import forms
from django_registration.forms import RegistrationForm
from users.models import User


class CustomRegistrationForm(RegistrationForm):
    # remove password confirmation
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(CustomRegistrationForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields.pop('password2')

    first_name = forms.CharField(max_length=30, label='First name')
    last_name = forms.CharField(max_length=30, label='Last name')

    class Meta(RegistrationForm.Meta):
        model = User
        fields = ('email', 'first_name', 'last_name')
        help_texts = {
            'password2': None
        }
```

Any thoughts on what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Hey, did to every resolve this? In have run into the same issue

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. Simply assign a username to the user and you'll be able to change is_active. Alternative you can prefill the username on signup/registration